# How to adjust trailing whitespace?

Tags: java

I am writing to a file in java but the strings that are input into the file are different, how do i adjust the trailing whitespace depending on the length of the string.

for example

```
First Name     Last Name     Address
----------     ---------     -------
Michael        Jordan        23 E. Jump Street
Larry          Bird          33 North Celtics Run
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Do you mean "how do I pad all strings to the same length"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [String.format()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
System.out.println(String.format("[%-20s]", "foo"));
```

will give you:

```
[foo                 ]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to write to a file with padding, then consider writing to the file using a PrintWriter, and using its printf(...) method. The API will tell you how to use this.

e.g.,

```
public class PrintfExample {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String formatString = "%-14s %-14s %-14s%n";
      String[][] data = {{"First Name", "Last Name", "Address"},
            {"---------", "---------", "---------"},
            {"Smith", "John", "100 Main St"}, 
            {"Michael", "Jordan", "23 E. Jump Street"},
            {"Larry", "Bird", "33 North Celtics Run"}};

      for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         // you would be writing to a File wrapped in a PrintWriter using printf
         // instead of to System.out (which is in fact a PrintWriter object),
         // but the technique is the same.
         System.out.printf(formatString, data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2]);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Both `PrintStream.printf()` and `String.format()` use same `java.util.Formatter()` class under the hood.

Comment: @MichałŠrajer: Yes, I agree.  1+ vote for your excellent answer by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Or like this, just use substring():

```
public class FormatFields {

private static final String [] [] data = {
        {"First Name", "Last Name", "Address"},
        {"----------", "---------", "-------"},
        {"Michael", "Jordan", "23 E. Jump Street"},
        {"Larry", "Bird", "33 North Celtics Run"}
};


private static final int FIELD_LENGTH = 20;
private static final String PADDING = "                    "; // 20 spaces

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {

            System.out.print((data[i][j] + PADDING).substring(0, FIELD_LENGTH));

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

}
```

Will give you

```
First Name          Last Name           Address             
----------          ---------           -------             
Michael             Jordan              23 E. Jump Street   
Larry               Bird                33 North Celtics Run
```

Comment: In java 5, the `java.util.Formatter` was introduced to stop people from doing this. No offense, but don't implement functionality already existing in standard library unless you REALLY need to support pre-java5 code.

Comment: Good point, but 1) the solution above also works for other languages; 2) it works with a variable number of values

Comment: 1.1) [java] was the only tag in this question. 1.2) A lot of languages has printf-like formating. 2) You can use Formatter with varaible number of values as well.