# PrintWriter println() without "spaces"

Tags: java, string, printwriter

I am trying to print some text line by line using the PrintWriter

I have tried various combinations such as

```
   1. mystring.trim() before println(mystring) 
   2. not using println and using \n instead
```

but my output file always ends up with a "trailing white space" at the end of each line. How can I remove that?

Comment: [FYI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7506771/2749470)

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question but if "trailing white space" is line separator like `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n` then you should probably read documentation of `println` and `print` methods.

Comment: @Pshemo Yeah, you got that right, I managed to resolve the issue by putting \r thanks

Answer (score 1):

`String.trim()` doesn't modify the string - it returns a new one with the spaces removed; this is because Strings in Java are immutable i.e. cannot be changed. You don't show your code, but I'm guessing this is the problem with your `trim` approach.

```
String mystring = "Hello   ";
mystring.trim();  // creates a new string, but doesn't assign it to anything
System.out.println(mystring);  // prints the original String unchanged
```

Instead, you can do:

```
String mystring = "Hello   ";
System.out.println(mystring.trim());  // prints the trimmed String
```

Comment: yeah i did assign the variable but it didnt work, i will edit my code in abit

Answer (score 0):

Type something along the lines of this:

```
println(mystring.trim())
```

That should work fine.

:)